# C++ Class diagram and {query}

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to learn UML class diagrams + c++ and I stumbled upon `{query}` being used after operation.
For example class diagram in picture does have `{query}` after operation.

[image]

Notice that I the (ref symbol) means `& symbol (const std::string&)`. 
What would `{query}` look code wise? Any tips?

Constructor is supposed to save parameter to attribute and then member function would return it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to p. 116 of UML 2.5:

> `<oper-property>` indicates the properties of the Operation.
>
> `<oper-property> ::= ‘redefines’ <oper-name> | ‘query’ | ‘ordered’ | ‘unordered’ | ‘unique’ | ‘nonunique’ | ‘seq’ | ‘sequence’ | <oper-constraint>`
>
> where
>
> - ‘query’ means that the Operation does not change the state of the system.

Basically you just can think of that as implementation of a property.

Comment: This operation-property is similar than a C++ `const` member function (where the const is placed after the parameter list), but much stronger since const just ensures that an instance does not change whereas {query} guarantees that no instance is changed.